# Sentence Transformation

Tags: sentence-construction

How do you transform

> We usually work too late to have much leisure time.

to a sentence in the form:

> So _____ that?

My answers:

1. We usually work so late that we cannot have much leisure time.
2. We usually work so late that we have/can have less leisure time.

Which is correct? And let me know any other possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your sentences are understandable.

> We usually work so late we cannot have much leisure time

is fine but a smoother sentence is

> We usually work so late we don't have much leisure time.
>   We usually work so late we don't have much **free** time.

Is a general statement about the effects of your work time on your personal time.

Using ***have*** **less leisure time** is asking for a comparison, "less time than whom?", which is not stated in your sentence but may not be necessary if surrounding context supplies it

Answer (score 0):

My natural response would be "We usually work so late that we *don't have* much leisure time". It's also possible to say "We usually work so late that we have less leisure time" (your option 2) - but not your option 1.

There is a subtle distinction between the two sentences: the first is a statement which stands on its own, whereas the second is comparative to a previous situation in which you had more leisure time, but now you have less.

"Less" is not the opposite of "much", but rather of "more". The inelegant "not much" is the opposite of "much".